# plotting SNS line chart with category x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

Im using this to group the values:

Code:

```
df['new_carat'] = pd.cut(x=df['carat'], bins=[0, 0.49, 0.69, 0.99, 1.99, 3], 
                         labels=['<0.5', '0.5-0.69', '0.7-0.99', '1-1.99', '>2'])
```

But when I try to plot line chart it gives me problem.

Code:

```
ax1 = sns.countplot(x='new_carat', data = df, palette='husl')
ax1.set_xlabel('Carat')
ax1.set_ylabel('Count')
ax1.set_title('Carat Count & Avg Price')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2 = sns.lineplot("new_carat",'price', data = df, color = red)
ax2.set_ylabel('Average Price')

plt.show
```

Error message saying "ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units"

Answer (score 1):

Changed the line plot to point plot and it resolved my problem.

```
ax1 = sns.countplot(x='new_carat', data = df, palette='husl')
ax1.set_xlabel('Carat')
ax1.set_ylabel('Count')
ax1.set_title('Carat Count & Avg Price')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2 = sns.pointplot(x="new_carat", y='price', data = df, color = 'red')
ax2.set_ylabel('Average Price')

plt.show
```